# How to include COUNT function in where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a customer records table. I'm trying to get the data for only customers that have visited 10+ times since a specific date. Here's the code I've got right now. Any help troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated!

```
    Select 
         customer_id,
         order_id,
         order_date
    from Table1
    where order_date > '2020-02-01'
    group by customer_id
    having count(customer_id)>=10
```

Comment: For one thing, you don't even say what's wrong. No feedback, no error message, etc.

Comment: this is orders, so what is visits?

Comment: Please provide table description some data examples and expected result. Your query will produce an error if `only_full_group_by` sql mode is enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not mix grouped and "normal" columns in a select

```
select *
from table1
where customer_id in
(
    Select customer_id
    from Table1
    where order_date > '2020-02-01'
    group by customer_id
    having count(*) >= 10
)
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly.